# Method for measuring co-occurence

Tags: statistics, combinations, data-analysis

I have a dataset that lists a large number of binary variables for each member of the populations. It basically looks like this:

```
Patient_Number    Measure_1    Measure_2    Measure_3    ...
0001               Yes           No           Yes
0002               No            No           Yes        ...
0003               Yes           Yes          Yes        ...
```

I want to assess which measures co-occur and to what extent. I am also interested to know if there are any combinations of measures that tend not to co-occur.

I am familiar with the R programming language but I do not know what an appropriate measure for this would be. My dataset is composed of ~400 patients and ~500 Measures but if I need to I can trim those down to subsets as small as 30 patients and 10 Measures.

Comment: you will never need to trim any data. The more the better. So you want to calculate the co-occurance matrix right? then what is the question? how to calculate?

Comment: What you want is called "measures of association" (for binary variables).  For each pair of variables (Measure_1, Measure_2 and so n)  you have defined a contingency table, so you can use the odds ratio.  This question would be better received on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you would like to have the question migrated to [stats.se], flag it for migration. Since it is on-topic here, we will not migrate it against the author's desire.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Understand that, but such questions about more practical aspects of statistics get better treatment at Cross Validated!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I wouldn't be surprised. But migrating on-topic questions against the OP's wishes is not a good thing, so we need the author's input. If the OP says "move it", we'll happily oblige, but if the OP says they'd still rather have it here, it should stay here.

Comment: As the OP, I request that you move this question to Cross Validated. I need all the help I can get and if thats the best place to get help then thats where this question should be